# Have some trouble with pausing and resuming the music via importing WMPLib

Tags: vb.net, wmplib

I already tried the way using currentPosition and yeah, i know what type of value does it return...
I wanted to use that return value as the position of music and when i resume the music, then the music continues at that position. But how do i make the music get started from that position?
Like, can i use the currentPosition method as an argument?
For example like "player.controls.play(currentPosition)" but i don't think that play() method gets any arguments...

To sum up the above, I'm using WMPLib and i wanna make music paused when i click button and also resume when i click another button.

is there any good solution maybe?